# Danfo.js : read .tsv files with readCSV() / read_csv()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, danfojs

in node.js environment with Danfo.js, reading .csv files is very easy with readCSV(), formerly read_csv(), as shown in [the official example:](https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/input-output/danfo.read_csv)

```
const dfd = require("danfojs-node")

dfd.readCSV("file:///home/Desktop/user_names.csv")
  .then(df => {
  
   df.head().print()

  }).catch(err=>{
     console.log(err);
  })
```

However, I can't find a way to read `.tsv` files.

Is there a way to read tab-delimited files with Danfo.js?

In the [source](https://github.com/opensource9ja/danfojs/blob/master/danfojs/src/io/reader.js#L21) I find the follwing comment:

```
 * @param {config} (Optional). A CSV Config object that contains configurations
 *     for reading and decoding from CSV file(s).
```

But I'm new to javascript coming from R/Python, didn't know what to do from there.

Comment: danfo.js is apparently a wrapper for tfjs backend. 
on tensorflow/js documentation, I found reference for the original function: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.csv How will I pass these parameters via Danfo.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use readCSV (formerly read_csv) a tsv:

```
dfd.readCSV("file.csv", configs={delimiter:'\t'} )
```

[Danfo.js documentation](https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/input-output/danfo.read_csv) says:

> Parameters: configs: object, optional
> Supported params are: ... csvConfigs: other supported Tensorflow csvConfig parameters. See https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.csv

Then [that page](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.csv) says:

> csvConfig object optional: ... delimiter (string) The string used to parse each line of the input file.

This means that parameter you include in `csvConfig` in `tf.data.csv()` can also be included in `configs` in `readCSV()`, e.g., if this works:

```
tf.data.csv(x,csvConfig={y:z})
```

then this will also work:

```
dfd.readCSV(x,configs={y:z})
```

PS: has anyone else noticed thast Danfo.js readCSV is insanely slow? It takes me 9 seconds to dfd.readCSV a 23MB tsv.  dfd.read_json brings this down to a still unusably slow 7 seconds. Compare this to 0.015 seconds to read a 22MB apache arrow file of the same data using apache-arrow js.

Comment: It's `readCSV()` now, not `read_csv()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've now changed read_csv to readCSV in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only a wrapper arount tfjs implementation and reading a tsv file is not yet implemented in tfjs, maybe you can consider

- replacing the tab with column and
- use the csv reader

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I was trying to do something like this in a TypeScript Project:

```
import * as dfd from "danfojs-node";

async function readFromCSV(path: string): Promise<void> => {
    const reportDataFrame  = await dfd.readCSV(path, {
        transform: (value: string) => {
            if(value == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return value;
        }
    });
    //rest of the code
}
```

It resulted in the following error:

```
Type '{ transform: (value: string) => string; }' has no properties in common with type 'CsvInputOptionsNode'.
```

As per the [documentation](https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/input-output/danfo.read_csv), readCSV should accept the config object as it in [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config).

As per my understanding, the problem was that the typescript compiler was not able to find the type ParseConfig (The class CsvInputOptionsNode extends ParseConfig), and therefore it was throwing an error.

I solved this problem by installing the types for papaparse. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/papaparse).

After adding types for papaparse, I updated the code as following:

```
import * as dfd from "danfojs-node";
import type { ParseConfig } from 'papaparse';

async function readFromCSV(): Promise<void> => {
    const config: ParseConfig = {
        transform: (value: string) => {
            if(value == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    const reportDataFrame  = await dfd.readCSV(path, config);
    //rest of the code
}
```